# AWS ELB Configuration for a multi-master

Tags: openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I have a multi-master Origin setup in AWS.  I have an ELB in front that uses SSL certificate configuration.

I'm having difficulty configuring the access to the Web console as it seems that the web sockets are being interrupted.  I can tell this because of the image below and the inability to access the logs or terminal for a pod in the web console.

[Server connection interrupted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yclth.png)

What is the proper configuration in AWS to allow the web console to function correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue.  I figured out the ELB configuration by following the CloudFormation template in the reference architecture here:

https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible-contrib/reference-architecture/aws-ansible/playbooks/roles/cloudformation-infra/files/greenfield.json

I also had an issue with the version of Chrome (50) and had to upgrade to version 55.  Basically I was getting 'ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME'.  This post pointed my towards upgrading Chrome:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/leVmLPNVISI